# Can someone please help me fix this Java code?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this following assignment every time i tried to fix an error it gave me error on error.

Given the following array of 5 rows and 5 columns, which contains the 
distances between cities:

Note that the city names are not in the array; the array contains 
the numeric entries only, which give the distance between the two 
cities represented by the row and column.

1. Write the statements to initialize an array distance with the 
   mileage data given above.
2. Write the statements to print the following menu, read in two 
   city numbers, and print the distance between the two cities:

To determine the mileage between cities, enter the numbers of 
two cities from the following list: 
1: Albany 4: NY 
2: Boston 5: Phila 
3: Hartford

Enter your city numbers:

** Test Case: Distance between Albany and NY && Distance between Hartford and Phila

```
public class DistanceofCities {

private static final String keyboard = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [][] distance = {
            {0, 171, 115, 141, 240},
            {171, 0, 103, 194, 333},
            {115, 103, 0, 120, 235},
            {141, 194, 120, 0, 104},
            {240, 333, 235, 104, 0}

    };

    int mileage;
    int first = -1, second = -1;

       System.out.println("To determine the mileage between cities, enter the \n");
       System.out.println("numbers of two cities from the following list:\n");
       System.out.println("      1:  Albany           4:  NY\n");
       System.out.println("      2:  Boston           5:  Phila\n");
       System.out.println("      3:  Hartford\n\n");
       System.out.println("Enter your city numbers ==> ");
       first = keyboard.nextInt();
       second = keyboard.nextInt();
       mileage = distance[first-1][second-1];
       System.out.println("The distance between your two cities is ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the errors; it's hard to diagnose a wall of code.

Comment: what are the input numbers you are trying. Most probably, you are trying an enter key between two input numbers and without checking you are directly converting to int.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use should define keyboard.Use `Scanner` class.

Try this
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class DistanceofCities {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [][] distance = {
            {0, 171, 115, 141, 240},
            {171, 0, 103, 194, 333},
            {115, 103, 0, 120, 235},
            {141, 194, 120, 0, 104},
            {240, 333, 235, 104, 0}

    };

    int mileage;
    int first = -1, second = -1;
       Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("To determine the mileage between cities, enter the \n");
       System.out.println("numbers of two cities from the following list:\n");
       System.out.println("      1:  Albany           4:  NY\n");
       System.out.println("      2:  Boston           5:  Phila\n");
       System.out.println("      3:  Hartford\n\n");
       System.out.println("Enter your city numbers ==> ");
       first = keyboard.nextInt();
       second = keyboard.nextInt();
       mileage = distance[first-1][second-1];
       System.out.println("The distance between your two cities is "+ mileage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the fixed code; Explanation below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceOfCities {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboardReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] distance = {
                {0, 171, 115, 141, 240},
                {171, 0, 103, 194, 333},
                {115, 103, 0, 120, 235},
                {141, 194, 120, 0, 104},
                {240, 333, 235, 104, 0}

        };

        int mileage;
        int first = -1, second = -1;

        System.out.println("To determine the mileage between cities, enter the \n");
        System.out.println("numbers of two cities from the following list:\n");
        System.out.println("      1:  Albany           4:  NY\n");
        System.out.println("      2:  Boston           5:  Phila\n");
        System.out.println("      3:  Hartford\n\n");
        System.out.println("Enter your city numbers ==> ");
        first = keyboardReader.nextInt();
        second = keyboardReader.nextInt();
        mileage = distance[first - 1][second - 1];
        System.out.println("The distance between your two cities is " + mileage + ".");

    }

}
```

Basically, to read keyboard input from the user, you need a **Scanner** object:

```
// This creates the scanner:
Scanner keyboardReader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The errors you were seeing were likely due to the fact you were trying to call the method nextInt() from a **null** object reference (i.e. pointer to nothing):

```
// Here, you defined keyboard as being null:
private static final String keyboard = null;

// Then, your code attempts to call a method from no object:
first = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Finally, don't forget to add mileage to the string that you get at the end:

```
// Add mileage:
 System.out.println("The distance between your two cities is " + mileage + ".");
```

Comment: Most likely the error was a compiler error to the effect that String has no method named nextInt().

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not printing out the mileage at the end. Try changing the last line of your code to:

```
System.out.println("The distance between your two cities is "+mileage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            int [][] distance = {
                    {0, 171, 115, 141, 240},
                    {171, 0, 103, 194, 333},
                    {115, 103, 0, 120, 235},
                    {141, 194, 120, 0, 104},
                    {240, 333, 235, 104, 0}

            };

            int mileage;
            int first = -1, second = -1;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.println("To determine the mileage between cities, enter the \n");
               System.out.println("numbers of two cities from the following list:\n");
               System.out.println("      1:  Albany           4:  NY\n");
               System.out.println("      2:  Boston           5:  Phila\n");
               System.out.println("      3:  Hartford\n\n");
               System.out.println("Enter your city numbers ==> ");
               first = in.nextInt();
               second = in.nextInt();
               mileage = distance[first-1][second-1];
               System.out.println("The distance between your two cities is "+mileage);
            }
```